# Get the value from the header

Tags: bash, api, curl, openstack

Is it possible to somehow get the value from the header and immediately load it into a variable?

Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
Date: Mon, 12 Jul 2021 10:23:01 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 3218
X-Subject-Token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Vary: X-Auth-Token
x-openstack-request-id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json
```

Need to get the `X-Subject-Token` into a variable.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sometimes you can use the `--write-out` option (a.k.a. `-w`) https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout but I’m not sure there is a variable that fits the `X-Subject-Token` case.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
var=$(curl -v ...|awk -F ':' '/^X-Subject-Token/ {print $2}')

echo "$var"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. And how to remove the problem at the beginning?

Comment: What do you mean by _problem at the beginning_ ?

Comment: At the moment, the output looks like this:
`#: cat token.txt`
`#:   Hkfdflkmgldmgdmgmddgdgm_gd_MMLM`
But have to:
`#: Hkfdflkmgldmgdmgmddgdgm_gd_MMLM`

Comment: The error was causing a new line..
echo $TOKEN123 |  sed -e 's/\r$//'

Comment: @Kaber: can you update the output of your curl command in the question, so that we can know what's the actual value of `X-Subject-Token` is getting reflected...thanks

Answer (score 0):

```sh
# read the _lines_ of the header into an array
mapfile -t header < <(curl --head ...)

declare -A values
for h in "${header[@]}"; do
    if [[ $h =~ ^([^:]+):" "(.*) ]]; then
        values[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    fi
done

declare -p values
echo "${values[X-Subject-Token]}"
```

Sometimes headers can span multiple lines or be encoded in a different charset, so this method is not infallible.

Also, header field names are case-insensitive, so you might want to do:

```sh
declare -l field    # variable has lower-case attribute
for h in "${header[@]}"; do
    if [[ $h =~ ^([^:]+):" "(.*) ]]; then
        field=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        value=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        values[$field]=$value
    fi
done
echo "${values[x-subject-token]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less elaborate solution using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
curl -v myurl.com 2>&1 | grep '< X-Subject-Token' | sed 's/.*: //'
```

Where

- `2>&1` Redirect stderr
- `grep '< X-Subject-Token'` Only keeps the line containing `< X-Subject-Token`
- `sed 's/.*: //'` strips the line *after* `:`  so we keep the value

Comment: The regex is greedy, so if the subject token contains a "colon space", you're not getting the whole value.